# $firebaseArray injector issue

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I am working with Angular and Firebase and getting a problem in injecting `$firebaseArray` in the controller. Here is the code:

```
myApp.controller("MeetingsController",
    ['$scope','$rootScope','$firebaseArray',
    function($scope,$firebaseArray,$rootScope){

    var ref = firebase.database().ref();
     var auth = firebase.auth();

        auth.onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
          if (user) {
            var data = firebase.database().ref('users/' + $rootScope.currentUser.$id + '/meetings');
            var meetingsInfo=$firebaseArray(data);

            $scope.addmeeting=function(){
                meetingsInfo.$add({
                    name:$scope.meetingname,
                    date:firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
                }).then(function(){
                    $scope.meetingname=' ';
                })
            };
          }
        });

}]);
```

The stack trace is attached below:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.6/$injector/unpr?p0=%24firebaseArrayProvider%20%3C-%20%24firebaseArray%20%3C-%20MeetingsController
O/<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:6:412
db/n.$injector<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:43:84
d@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:40:344
db/U<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:43:144
d@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:40:344
e@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:41:78
h/<.instantiate@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:41:445
ff/this.$get</<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:90:1
A/<.link@file:///E:/Ex_Files_AngularJS_DataDriven/Ex_Files_AngularJS_DataDriven/Exercise%20Files/ch01/01_02/angulardata/js/lib/angular/angular-route.min.js:7:268
bb/<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:16:228
ia@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:81:35
n@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:66:176
g@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:58:429
aa/<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:58:67
ac/<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:62:428
d@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:59:422
l@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:63:447
x@file:///E:/Ex_Files_AngularJS_DataDriven/Ex_Files_AngularJS_DataDriven/Exercise%20Files/ch01/01_02/angulardata/js/lib/angular/angular-route.min.js:6:364
uf/this.$get</m.prototype.$broadcast@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:147:483
m/<@file:///E:/Ex_Files_AngularJS_DataDriven/Ex_Files_AngularJS_DataDriven/Exercise%20Files/ch01/01_02/angulardata/js/lib/angular/angular-route.min.js:11:408
e/<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:130:409
uf/this.$get</m.prototype.$eval@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:145:103
uf/this.$get</m.prototype.$digest@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:142:165
uf/this.$get</m.prototype.$apply@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:145:399
l@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:97:248
D@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:101:373
fg/</w.onload@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:102:397
<main class="cf ng-scope" ng-view="">
```

I am following the current version of Firebase. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you making sure to inject firebase into your module  like var app =  angular.module("sampleApp", ["firebase"]);

Comment: @MattyM Thanks matty. Solved the issue. I had one more question. What is the equivalent of `firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` in current version of firebase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order is not correct, change it like this,

```
myApp.controller("MeetingsController",'$scope','$rootScope','$firebaseArray',
    function($scope,$rootScope,$firebaseArray){
```

}

Also make sure you have injected 'firebase' as a dependency to your module,

```
var app = angular.module("sampleApp", ["firebase"]);
```

[`DEMO APP`](https://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/b7fkpj1o/)

Comment: Yes after your answer I did correct it. But still no change in error. I don't think I am missing anything here. Am I? @sajeetharan

Comment: @AakashThakur because i made a change, there was extra comma, check this sample fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/b7fkpj1o/

Comment: This is my current controller:  myApp.controller("MeetingsController",
 ['$scope','$rootScope','$firebaseArray',
 function($scope,$rootScope,$firebaseArray)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124235/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-aakash-thakur).

Comment: Thanks a lot sajee for your responses. Didn't include `firebase` as a dependency in my module before. Now works correctly. @sajeetharan